# Error building QtCore

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to build QtCore.lib and I get this weird error.

```
PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "MOC kernel\qtimer.cpp"
```

I am able to build qtmain.lib but not able tp go any further.

moc.exe is available in bin folder and the path is added to my PATH.
kernel\qtimer.cpp file is also present in corelib folder.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated. I am building with Qt-4.5.2 source.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use this rather ancient Qt version?

Answer (score 0):

In Qt 4.5.2 moc.exe has some issues. An email I sent to Qt Support mentions it moc'ing files that were not modified. It could have further issues, which could be related to what you are experiencing.

Sorry I can't recall the exact details. To make things worse the link Qt Support had sent me at the time is broken.

They had suggested using 4.5.3. I think we ended up staying on 4.5.1, which we are still using today, although the move to 4.7.x. is occurring as I write this. :)